# FIRAuth token refresh fails on simulator but works on real device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, callback

So I've been working with FIRAuth to log users into my app with no real problems up until yesterday when I was greeted by this awful message.

[image]

Not being terribly familiar with this part of Firebase, I waited for the Token auto-refresh to occur a few times, just to see if my firebase calls would ever come back to me, but sadly they never did.

[image: The method that gets called.]
Above is the method that I'm calling, which I show evidence of in the next picture:

[image]
Sadly the second breakpoint is never reached, hence leading me to believe that the Firebase call cannot even return an error because of the the Token issue.

Here's the strangest thing: this bug **only** occurs on **simulator**. Running the app on my personal device doesn't result in any issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated; also don't hesitate to ask for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Alright well I managed to fix it by switching Simulator devices. Specifically I went from an iPhone 7 Plus to an iPhone 6, but it's curious because I've attempted restarting the simulator before this. Hope this helps anyone who runs into the same problem that I did!